# renaming files in python causes Device or resource busy

Tags: python, linux

I am writing a script with python.

First, let me show you the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/jiewei/PycharmProjects/TestEngine/test/test_multiple_classes.py", line 23, in test_create_symlink_and_run_test_in_devbench_but_is_called_in_vdi
    self.sm.make_backups(self.dev_path)
File "testengine/SymlinkManger.py", line 24, in make_backups
    self.make_backup(file_path)
File "testengine/SymlinkManger.py", line 19, in make_backup
    os.rename(file_path, new_name)
OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy
```

Then here are method causing the problem:

```
def make_backup(self, file_path):
    name = os.path.basename(file_path)
    folder_path = os.path.dirname(file_path)
    if not name.startswith('backup_'):
        new_name = os.path.join(folder_path,"backup_"+name)
        os.rename(file_path, new_name)

def make_backups(self, folder_path):
    for file in folder_path:
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file)
        self.make_backup(file_path)
```

Do I need to create threads to solve this problem? I guess the cause is os is been used by multiple progress and this cause the exception.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely *don't* need threads to solve this. It just looks you're renaming something that is actually in use...

Looking at the [Linux manpage for the rename() call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html), you might get EBUSY (error 16) when renaming a directory that's in use:

> The rename fails because oldpath or newpath is a directory that is in
>   use by some process (perhaps as current working directory, or as root
>   directory, or because it was open for reading) or is in use by the
>   system (for example as mount point), while the system considers this
>   an error.  (Note that there is no requirement to return EBUSY in such
>   cases—there is nothing wrong with doing the rename anyway—but it is
>   allowed to return EBUSY if the system cannot otherwise handle such
>   situations.)

Comment: but I am not renaming any folders or anything is been used. I created some files only for testing. Not any applications will use those files.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a `print(file_path, new_name)` before the `os.rename()` call to make sure your assumptions about the renames are right...

Comment: seems something weird happened and you are correct. Thank you for the advice!